# angular 2 How to remove the color of list on delete

Tags: angular

Is it possible to add color to a list on click and remove the same by using a button in same sequence as the color was applied. thanks in advance.
for e g. i have list of 5 items and they are selected in the order 1,3,5,4,2.
is it possible to remove the color through a button in the same order as they are applied?

```
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let content of fieldList; let x =
           index" (click)="whenClicked[x]=!whenClicked[x]" 
          [style.background-color] = "whenClicked[x]  ? '#20a8d8 ' : ''" 
              class="list-group-item" >
              {{content.name}}
            </li>
          </ul>

          <button (click)='onDelete()'>Delete</button>


          and in the TS 
              class NewComponent {
            whenClicked = [false,false];
            arrOne: any =[];

            fieldsIndex(x: string) {
            this.arrOne.push({x});
            console.log(this.arrOne);}

            onDelete(){
            }


}
```

Comment: i was able to add color to the list but unable to remove them

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you are able to store the sequence in an array. You'll just have to write the logic or at least post what you have tried so far.

Comment: by using the fieldsIndex() i was able to capture and push the index number in an object, but i am still at loss as to how to write the function to delete it.